# Why in GKE (Private Cluster) the destination only sees Pod IP instead of Node IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-egress

I'm still learning GKE and I have set up a private cluster.

The problem I have is that when I send traffic outside the cluster from a Pod (usually by sending an HTTP request) to an external system, the external system only sees the IP address from the Pod, I was expecting the external system to see the node IP instead so that the IP range can be whitelisted.

I have also configured a Cloud NAT on my cluster, but I don't understand why the Pod IP is visible by the external system. Could you please provide a valid explanation of why this is happening?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips) doc provided by @Arnau Senserrich. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Is your cluster VPC-native?
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips

It's the only thing coming to my head right now that can explain this behaviour.